# How to add A Share button on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Here's The Code

```
              Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        widget.data.judul,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text(
                    widget.data.penulis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.data.waktu,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
                  child: Text(widget.data.isi)),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

> I want to have a Share button on the button that share the content
> inside the screen, that shows the title and some of the description,
> data[index].judul is title, and data[index].isi is description

Comment: you want to share the title and the data via email or SMS or something else?

Comment: @SaifulIslam I want to share via Email,SMS and Whatsapp

Comment: okay then design a share button and on onclick of this button you can share your content via using this package. https://pub.dev/packages/share

Comment: if you have any other questions let me know.

Comment: @SaifulIslam can i use API on that Package?

Comment: you want to share Api url? of what? I did not get you. please explain to me.

Comment: @SaifulIslam so I get all of the title and the description from API so can i call them both inside the share?

Comment: Yes, you can. ..

Comment: @SaifulIslam I just figure it out! Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 32, 16, 16),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 20, 16, 20),
                  child: Text(
                   "Share",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "medium",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Share.share( 
                          data[index].judul.toString(), 
                          subject: data[index].isi.toString()
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
```

You can even share files and in most cases, we use firebase dynamic link sharing.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

Share plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/share

Comment: It shows this error `error: The argument type 'String Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

Comment: data[index].judul.**toString()**, use first parentheses ... I have edited.

Comment: Can this share makes people open the app? or maybe open Appstore or playstore to make them download the app?

Comment: yes. for dynamic landing you need to use dynamic links

Answer (score 0):

Here use this plugin.

---

[Share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share)
**share: ^2.0.1**

```
try {
     await Share.share(
        '${data[index].judul}',subject:'${data[index].isi}'
      );
 } on PlatformException {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text(
   "Platform not support this feature",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ));
} on MissingPluginException {
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
 content: Text(
 "Feature Not Available",
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ));
 } catch (er) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
   .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
   content: Text("Error: $er"),
   ));
}
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: In the `OnPressed`/`onTap` method of any button.

Answer (score 0):

To share data from one app to another app you can use [share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share)
Example,

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
```

For More example and detailed info visit [codewithflutter.com](https://codewithflutter.com/flutter-share-data-to-another-application/)